# Function take css code then add it to wp_head

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there any way to create a function that take css code variable then add it to wp_head?

Something like this:

```
function za_button ($border_radius) {
    $css = '.za-btn-'.$uid.' { border-radius:'. $border_radius .'px; }';
    add_to_wp_head($css);
}
```

This way didn't work with me

```
function za_button ($border_radius) {
    $css = '.za-btn-'.$uid.' { border-radius:'. $border_radius .'px; }';
    $css = <style>' . $css . '</style>
    add_action( 'wp_head', function () { echo $css; });
}
```

Comment: As i suggest use jQuery to apply CSS as your value is coming dynamically.

Comment: "This way didn't work with me" - what do you mean? Do you have any error on front?

Comment: I don't recommend doing this using javascript or jQuery - it just added extra unnecessary processing to the client side. You have a lot of problems with the code you are trying to use, from syntax errors to incorrect logic and un-initialised variables. Please fix the syntax errors and if you are still having problems lease [edit] your question with the *specific* details of the errors/problems.